# Subtracting two pointers giving unexpected result

Tags: c, pointers, subtraction

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *p = 100;
    int *q = 92;
    printf("%d\n", p - q);  //prints 2
}
```

Shouldn't the output of above program be 8?

Instead I get 2.

Comment: Deceasing pointers? Sounds creepy.

Comment: Why do you expect 8?

Comment: 100-92 should be 8 not 2

Comment: You may only subtract pointers that point into the same data object. Differences are calculated in numbers of elements, not in bytes.

Comment: They are `int` not `char`.  So 8 bytes in difference is `2*sizeof(int)`

Comment: @MohammadJaber try replacing `int` with `char` and see what happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Undefined behavior aside, this is the behavior that you get with pointer arithmetic: when it is legal to subtract pointers, their difference represents the number of data items between the pointers. In case of `int` which on your system uses four bytes per `int`, the difference between pointers that are eight-bytes apart is `(8 / 4)`, which works out to `2`.

Here is a version that has no undefined behavior:

```
int data[10];
int *p = &data[2];
int *q = &data[0];
// The difference between two pointers computed as pointer difference
ptrdiff_t pdiff = p - q;
intptr_t ip = (intptr_t)((void*)p);
intptr_t iq = (intptr_t)((void*)q);
// The difference between two pointers computed as integer difference
int idiff = ip - iq;
printf("%td %d\n", pdiff, idiff);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Kjyila)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157386/discussion-on-answer-by-dasblinkenlight-subtracting-two-pointers-giving-unexpect).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You cannot simply subtract two "arbitrary" pointers. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6/P9

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. [....]

Also, as mentioned above, if you correctly subtract two pointers, the result would be of type `ptrdiff_t` and you should use `%td` to print the result.

---

That being said, the initialization

```
 int *p = 100;
```

looks quite wrong itself !! To clarify, it **does not** store a value of `100` to the memory location pointed by (*question: where does it point to?*) `p`. It attempts to sets the pointer variable itself with an integer value of `100` which seems to be a constraint violation in itself.

Comment: This is not the UB. This is implementation defined part. As you probably know it is in the common use in the low level programming world (otherwise there is no chance to access the hardware in C). Example: `ADC_TypeDef *ADC1 = ((ADC_TypeDef *) ((((uint32_t)0x40000000U) + 0x10000000U) + 0x00000100U))`

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Are you referring to the subtraction? AFAIK, it's UB as stated by standard.

Comment: no - to the  `int *p = 100;`. Abstracting from the sense of the 100.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int *p = 100;
int *q = 92;
```

is already invalid C. In C you cannot initialize pointers with arbitrary integer values. There's no implicit integer-to-pointer conversion in the language, aside from conversion from null-pointer constant `0`. If you need to force a specific integer value into a pointer for some reason, you have to use an explicit cast (e.g. `int *p = (int *) 100;`).

Even if your code somehow compiles, its behavior in not defined by C language, which means that there's no "should be" answer here.

Comment: In C generally yos, but as usually in the embedded programming pointers keep the address, it is 100% ok. The code will compile, otherwise no uC programming would be possible.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: My answer basically refers to the absence of explicit casts. I don't see how "no uC programming would be possible", because you can simply add the cast and make the code compliant. As for "pointer keeping the address" - yes, that's how it normally works. I have nothing against it. Just remember to use a cast.

Comment: Cast suppresses warning. Does not make the code "compilable". It is C not C++ where it will not compile.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Firstly, there's no difference between C and C++ in this regard. Secondly, there's no such thing as "warning" in C. The language knows only *diagnostic messages*. And some *diagnostic messages* indicate *constraint violations*. This specific diagnostic message does. The fact that in your compiler it is formatted as "warning" does not mean anything. Or it might mean that you configured your compiler incorrectly.

Comment: there is a significant difference. One example: `int *foo; foo = malloc(sizeof int);` compile it :) as C & C++, (Now about the messages)Very interesting but 100% incorrect as annex J of the standard has the title: `Common warnings`.  your 'diagnostic messages' =  'message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the implementation's message output'. For more details read `5.1.1.3 Diagnostics`. I think your comments are about your own language - but definitely not about the C

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Annex J is an **informative** annex, not a **normative** annex. Basically, it is just a relaxed chit-chat about the language, nothing serious. One more time (and again, this is for you to memorize without questioning, not to argue): C language does not have any "warnings" or "errors", it has only *diagnostic messages*.

Comment: And, as I said above, since at this point you are making your first baby steps in understanding C language, learn to use `-pedantic-errors` in order to tell "harmless warnings" from "warnings" that designate actual errors. Once you learn the language well enough, you'll be able to do it without such external aids. But for now: `-pedantic-errors` is your best friend, without whom you are not allowed to even touch C code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard ([N1570](http://iso-9899.info/n1570.html))

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.

Answer (score 0):

These are integer pointers, `sizeof(int)` is 4. Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the size of the thing pointed to. Therefore the "raw" difference in bytes is divided by 4. Also, the result is a `ptrdiff_t` so `%d` is unlikely to cut it.

But please note, what you are doing is technically undefined behaviour as Sourav points out. It works in the most common environments almost by accident. However, if p and q point into the same array, the behaviour is defined.

```
int a[100];
int *p = a + 23;
int *q = a + 25;

printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)a); // some number
printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)p); // some number + 92
printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)q); // some number + 100
printf("%ld\n", q - p); // 2
```